# ¿Me podrían explicar cómo cómo es que funciona esta parte del código? Quisiera entender su sintaxis

Tags: javascript

buenas noches. Hace poco he estado llevando un curso de lógica de programación en JavaScript y hay unos puntos que me volaron la cabeza. Me gustaría que me pudieran ayudar a entender mejor esta parte del código.

**Como primera parte** se encuentra el **valor booleano**: Por ejemplo, me gustaría saber cómo es que funciona ya que si el **valor de la variable "encontrado"** le pongo como **verdadero (true)** en vez de false como se ve abajo, el código **solo muestra la respuesta que tiene vinculado un "bool como verdadero"** por medio del pop-up generado por el **alert** dentro de la condicional.

Para que puedan entender mejor podrían copiar el código completo y solo cambiar el false a true de la variable "encontrado".

```
var encontrado = false;
```

A parte de ello, también he tenido esta duda con esta fracción del código: Aquí, por ejemplo, **no sé porque se pone el corchete en **contador**.** Este, **"elegido[contador]"**.

```
if (parseInt(input.value) == elegido[contador]){
```

Aquí dejo el código completo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Juego secreto V1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Juego secreto V1</h1>
    <input type="text">
    <button>Enviar</button>
</body>

<script>


    var elegido = [3,5,7,9,11,13]; 
    var input = document.querySelector("input");

    input.focus();

    function verificar() { 

        var encontrado = false;

        for (var contador = 0; contador < elegido.length; contador ++){

            if (parseInt(input.value) == elegido[contador]){ /* Se pasó el índice de la variable contador */
                alert("Has acertado.");
                encontrado = true;
                break;  
            }
        }

        if( encontrado == false){

            alert("Te has equivocado.");
        }
        
        input.focus();
        input.value = ""; 

    }

    var boton = document.querySelector("button");  
     boton.onclick = verificar;

</script>

</html>
```

Quedo atento a sus mensajes.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: elegido es un array, y se puede acceder a los valores del array mediante la notación de corchetes, que indica su número de índice en el array. Por ejemplo, elemento[2] nos devolveria el 7 (los indices empiezan por la posición 0).  En cuanto al `encontrado`, lo que está haciendo es predefinirlo como `false`, pero si luego cumple el siguiente condicional **if** entonces pasa a ser `true` para que no salte el siguiente `alert` de que se ha equivocado.

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente al presionar el botón se dispara la función verificar, antes de declarar la función se captura el input y se declara un array(lista) con números.

Luego lo que pasa adentro de la funcion es que se itera o se recorren todos los elementos del array y se compara el valor del input (al cual se le hace un parseInt para pasarlo a tipo number ya que este es un string) con el array en la posición que le corresponde a contador, ahí viene el elegido[contador], en cada iteración del for contador valdrá 1 más que en la vuelta anterior, entonces si contador vale 0 y se pone elegido[contador] se está accediendo a valor en la posición 0 del array, es decir al primer valor.. Luego hace lo mismo con el siguiente valor del array y así sucesivamente.

Si en algún momento el valor del array recorrido es = al valor del input se pone encontrado en true, se dispara el alert("Has acertado") y se hace un break lo cual corta el loop (o sea el for)..

Si en ningún momento esa comparación se cumple se terminan de hacer todas las iteraciones del for y se sigue con el código, ahí chequea si encontrado sigue en false lo cual sucede si el valor ingresado en el input no fue igual a ninguno de los valores recorridos del array, en ese caso hace el alert("Te has equivocado"), vuelve a poner el foco en el input y borra el valor del input.